# I cannot get video to resize with flvplayback and as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, video, flvplayback

I have made a flash player again, this time we needed it to play .mov and use fullscreen funstions with seeks n other basic features.
Working fine, I am using a flvplayback component with as3.

Now the problem, The video is resized to something like 240x240 when the video is 360x280.

When I try something like:

```
        debugTxt.text = "video.w "+video.width +" ,h "+video.height;
```

where video is my flvplayback component.

Any suggestion or code snippet will be great help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution for this scaling issue.

Just the one line of code addition

video.scaleMode = VideoScaleMode.EXACT_FIT;

and we are done